# Escape \n when exporting CSV using COPY command

Tags: postgresql, psql, aws-glue

I need to export various tables in CSV for AWS Glue Catalog and I just noticed a major showstopper:

> COPY command does not escape new line inputs in columns, only quotes them.

What confuses me even more is that I can switch to TEXT and get the format right - escape the special characters - but I cannot have HEADER in that format!

```
COPY (%s) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' NULL ''
```

Is there a way to get both HEADER and to escape the new line through COPY command?

I'm hoping that it's my overlook as the code is obviously there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text` format does *not* produce CSV, that is why you cannot get headers or change the delimiter.  It is the “internal” tab-separated format of PostgreSQL.

There are no provisions to replace newlines with `\n` in a CSV file, and indeed that would produce invalid CSV (according to what most people think; there is no standard).

You'll have to post-process the file.

Comment: I suspected that. What I don't like is the fact that as a user I'm limited by whoever decided what should be the standard even though in the documentation they themselves recognise lack of standards: `Many programs produce strange and occasionally perverse CSV files, so the file format is more a convention than a standard`. They have the feature that escapes the `\n` and they use it for `TEXT` format, but I cannot decide to use the same thing when doing the `CSV` extract.

Comment: That's what you get from no standard :^(